# Why @FetchRequest fails in ContentView

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nsfetchrequest

I have following code in my SwiftUI ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var search = ""
@State private var selectedBookID: Int64? = 0

@FetchRequest(entity: Books.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Books.bokName, ascending: true)])
var books: FetchedResults<Books>

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                NavigationLink("New book...", destination: BookView(isNew: true)).padding(.leading)
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink("Authors...", destination: AuthorView())
                NavigationLink("Genres...", destination: GenreView()).padding(.trailing)
            }.padding(.vertical)
            TextField("Search...", text: $search).padding(.horizontal)
            List(books, id: \Books.bokID, selection: $selectedBookID) { book in
                NavigationLink(book.bokName!, destination: BookView(isNew: false)).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

and it fails during app launching with error "No NSEntityDescriptions in any model claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'Books' so +entity is confused.  Have you loaded your NSManagedObjectModel yet ?".
It works quite fine for all other views in the same app.
Note it's macOS app.
Thanks.

Comment: Try clean the project, then build again. Usually fixes issues like this for CoreData, because CoreData creates the models for you.

Comment: I cleaned Build Folder via Product menu in XCode. I also deleted whole project folder in DerivedData and restarted Xcode but error persists. It looks to me that I tries to access CoreData stack prior it's fully initialized because very similar codes are running fine in other views: Issue is just with ContentView.

Comment: Just want to double check, it's not the spelling of `\Books.bokName`? You appear to spell "book" as "bok" a few times and I'm not sure if it is a typo.

Comment: I understand you come from but bokName is correct name.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way - simply took @FetchRequest part out of ContentView and placed it into extra struct like below

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                NavigationLink("New book...", destination: BookView(isNew: true)).padding(.leading)
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink("Authors...", destination: AuthorView())
                NavigationLink("Genres...", destination: GenreView()).padding(.trailing)
            }.padding(.vertical)
            BookList()
        }
    }
}
}

struct BookList: View {

@State private var search = ""
@State private var selectedBookID: Int64? = 0

@FetchRequest(entity: Books.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Books.bokName, ascending: true)])
var books: FetchedResults<Books>

var body: some View {
    TextField("Search...", text: $search).padding(.horizontal)
    List(books, id: \Books.bokID, selection: $selectedBookID) { book in
        NavigationLink(book.bokName!, destination: BookView(isNew: false)).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
}
}
```